# I wrote a trigger which is not working. Am I missing something?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON table1
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO table2
        VALUES (NEW.request_id, NEW.user_concurrent_program_name,
                NEW.argument_text, NEW.comments, NEW.acknowledgement_status,
                SYSDATE, NEW.acknowledged_by);
END;
/
```

But this throws the below error:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/4      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
3/17     PLS-00201: identifier 'NEW.REQUEST_ID' must be declared
```

Isn't 'NEW' supposed to be the new row details being inserted into the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following code

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON table1
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO table2
        VALUES (:NEW.request_id, :NEW.user_concurrent_program_name,
                :NEW.argument_text, :NEW.comments, :NEW.acknowledgement_status,
                SYSDATE, :NEW.acknowledged_by);
END;
/
```

I have just put **:** in inserting values ahead of ANew keyword.